# Is it possible to specify an npm package as a catkin dependency?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Specifically, I'm creating a package that uses yeoman, bower, and grunt. So I'd like for anyone to be able to run `rosdep install mypackage` and not only get nodejs, but also have something like `npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli` be run automatically.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203403/is-it-possible-to-specify-an-npm-package-as-a-catkin-dependency?/) by [justinhuang](https://answers.ros.org/users/21672/justinhuang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, but support could be added.

To do this you would need to add support for npm in `rosdep`. A good place to start would be to look at support for `pip` and `gem` in `rosdep`, especially `gem` since it was added recently. Then you could specify `npm` keys in the rosdep database and in your package's package.xml and have the `rosdep` CLI install them for you.

One caveat with all of these cross platform package managers is that when doing binary packaging, we cannot build a `.deb` for example of a package which depends on something that is not installed from `apt-get`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1